# Assigning set of commands to buttons created using Zenity

Tags: linux, unix, zenity

I want to create a GUI using Zenity.

I want all below options in a single GUI:

1. Add a button => able to execute set of Unix commands (sourcing a file containing Unix commands), if button is clicked;
2. Add checklist => Suppose option1 is a variable, and its values can be a,b,c,d then its values can be set to `a` or `b` or `c` or `d` via a checklist.
3. Executing `if` and `else` command of Unix using Zenity.

I have tried the following:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
zenity --question --text="Ref/?" rc=$?
if [ "${rc}" == "1" ]; then
    setenv REF 1
fi 
setenv REF 0
```

The output is:

```sh
rc=0: Command not found.
rc: Undefined variable.
`$REF: Undefined variable`
```

However I expect `$REF` to be set to either `1` or `0`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide a minimal example to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Added required information
@octobus

Answer (score 0):

Minor typos. Assuming bash/dash as default shell.

```
#!/bin/sh
zenity --question --text="Ref/?"
set rc=$status
if ("${rc}" == "1" ] ) then
    setenv REF 1
else
    setenv REF 0
end
```

Comment: Its still not working for me. I' m getting the same error

Comment: Please run with ‘set -x’ and share output

Comment: I did not get you. How to set x ?

Comment: Current error is :
rc=1: Command not found.
rc: Undefined variable.

Comment: One more thing, i want $REF a variable to be set, because i want to use it later in my script

Comment: set: Variable name must begin with a letter.
Ouput after set -x added before zenity line

Comment: What she’ll do you use ? Are you running tcsh/csh ?

Comment: I am using tcsh

Comment: Original posting was mixing sh and tcsh. Did you try with sh/bash. Csh/tcsh are not practical for scripting

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
export REF=0
# If user press Yes, set REF to 1
if zenity --question --text="Ref/?"; then
    REF=1
fi
```

If you press the button `No`, `REF` will be set to `0`, otherwise, it will be set to `1`. You need to adjust it for the logic in your script.

Comment: I tried to source the code, i get below error:
export: Command not found.
if: Expression Syntax.